# how to display array and convert from number to string?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$jobid = $_GET['idx'];
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE job_idx = '$jobid' ";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
if($row["job_specialization"] == '228')
{ $spec.=" Accounting ";}
if($row["job_specialization"] == '24')
{ $spec.=" Admin / Clerical / Secretarial ";}
if($row["job_specialization"] == '3')
{ $spec.=" Audit & Taxation ";}
if($row["job_specialization"] == '5')
{ $spec.=" Banking / Finance / Investment / Credit Control ";}
}

echo "$spec";
```

in my database, i managed to insert an array of maximum 3 values only which are 228,24, 3.
i can display back these numbers at preview-ad3.php but how to change the value into words as stated above ? for example.

```
echo $spec;
```

it will be like this
    Accounting,Admin / Clerical / Secretarial, Audit & Taxation

i would appreciate if someone can help me on this as i'm only left this thing to complete my job. thanks :D

---

answer updated

```
    $jobarr = explode(",", $row['job_specialization']); 

if(in_array("228", $jobarr))
{ $spec.=" Accounting,";}
    if(in_array("3", $jobarr))
{ $spec.=" Audit & Taxation,";}
```

i tried this code. and it works well ! thanks guys for helping anyway. :)

Comment: Mmmm... There sure _must_ be a way to make that look DRYer...

Comment: reallyy. i can make it short if u want.

Comment: You could use an array, or a database table to hold that map. The actual question is why you are asking how to print the associated text, if your current (awful) code already does that. -- (It's probably pointless to mention the SQL security gaps in your code.)

Comment: can u explain more details ?
i can print the numbers. but i want it to change from number to words.

Comment: **sql injection alert**

Answer (score 0):

A proper way of doing so is to create a table to hold the information about job details so your query would look like this:

```
SELECT j.*, i.title 
FROM job AS j INNER JOIN job_info AS i ON j.job_idx=i.id 
WHERE j.job_idx = '$jobid'
```

Comment: hmm i still wonder why i should join the table ?
this code is on preview-ad3.php 
its like im displaying all data from database here.

Comment: Your approach is very inefficient and I hope you are not using it in production. There is minimal overhead when using simple joins but as a benefit you would have less headache maintaining consistency through your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going the ignore the fact that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, and an intruder can do some nasty things in your database if you don't sanitize the GET variable or use prepared statements to perform the query.

To my understanding, your database stores the job_specialization by an ID, and you want to map a number to a name.

The long way would be to alter your current database schema, have two tables one for job_specialization with an id, and a name column, and have those tables joined in order to retrieve the name of the job_specialization from the database.

The other way, just to make your code a bit readable, I would use the `define` function, so your code would look like as follows:

```
define('ACCOUNTING','228');
define('SECRETARIAL','24');
define('AUDIT','3');
define('BANKING','5');

$jobid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['idx']);
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM job WHERE job_idx = '$jobid' ";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

    switch($row['job_specialization']) {
     case ACCOUNTING:
         $spec.=" Accounting ";
         break;
     case SECRETARIAL:
         $spec.="Secretarial ";
         break;
    }

}

echo $spec;
```

Then again, that might not be the best code performance-wise speaking, but at least is more readable than the one you posted.

Answer (score 0):

hop this help

```
$spec_map = array('228'=>'Accounting',
                '24'=>' Admin / Clerical / Secretarial',
                 '3' =>'Audit & Taxation',
                 '5'=>'Banking / Finance / Investment / Credit Control'
                );

$spec='';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
$spec .= $spec?',':'';
$spec .= $spec_map[$row["job_specialization"]];
} 

echo $spec;
```

Comment: didnt work. do we have a simple way to do this ?  because i think if this thing is not an array but a single value, it would be easier to display and convert number to word. am i right ?

Comment: i dont know what u mean 'easier'